# No matching constructor for initialization of "Type"

Tags: c++, constructor, sfml

I am writing a board game using C++ (with SFML2.2 library, Xcode 6.1.1). I created two classes: block and board. The idea is to create a 4x4 vector of blocks inside board. The codes are below:

In block.h

```
#ifndef __Game1024__block__
#define __Game1024__block__
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream> 
#endif /* defined(__Game1024__block__) */

using namespace std;

class block{
public:
    sf::RectangleShape rect;
    sf::Text text;
    block();
    block(const int X,const int Y,const double size, const double blockSize, const double charSize, const int value, const sf::Color fillColor, const sf::Color textColor);
};
```

In block.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "block.h"

using namespace std;

block::block(){}

block::block(const int X,const int Y,const double size, const double blockSize, const double charSize, const int value, const sf::Color fillColor, const sf::Color textColor){

    double centerX = (X+0.5)*size;
    double centerY = (Y+0.5)*size;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << value;
    string sval = ss.str();

    rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(blockSize,blockSize));
    rect.setOrigin(blockSize/2.0, blockSize/2.0);
    rect.setPosition(centerX, centerY);
    rect.setFillColor(fillColor);

    text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
    text.setCharacterSize(charSize);
    text.setString(sval);
    text.setColor(textColor);
    text.setOrigin(text.getLocalBounds().width/2.0, text.getLocalBounds().height);
    text.setPosition(centerX, centerY);
 }
```

In board.h

```
#ifndef __Game1024__board__
#define __Game1024__board__
#include <stdio.h>
#endif /* defined(__Game1024__board__) */
#include <vector>
#include "block.h"
using namespace std;

class board{
private:
    int winSizeX;
    int winSizeY;
    int margin;
    double charSize;
public:
    vector<vector<block>> matrix;
    board();
    board(int winSizeX_,int winSizeY_,int margin_, double charSize_);
    void draw();
};
```

And in board.cpp

```
#include "board.h"
//#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "block.h"
using namespace std;

board::board(){}

board::board(int winSizeX_,int winSizeY_,int margin_, double charSize_){
    winSizeX = winSizeX_;
    winSizeY = winSizeY_;
    margin = margin_;
    charSize = charSize_;
    matrix = vector<vector<block>>(4,vector<block>(4));

    double size = winSizeX/4.0; // = 256
    double blockSize = size - 2*margin;
    const sf::Color fillColor = sf::Color::Red;
    const sf::Color textColor = sf::Color::White;

    sf::Font font;
    if(!font.loadFromFile("./sansation.ttf")){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
            int value = 4*j + i + 1;
            matrix[i][j] = block(i,j,size,blockSize, charSize,value,fillColor,textColor);
            matrix[i][j].text.setFont(font);
            matrix[i][j].text.setOrigin(matrix[i][j].text.getLocalBounds().width/2.0,b[i][j].text.getLocalBounds().height);
        }
    }
}
```

The error comes from **board.cpp**

```
matrix[i][j] = block(i,j,size,blockSize, charSize,value,fillColor,textColor);
```

One weird thing is when I typed matrix[i][j] = block, the autofill of my IDE (Xcode) will generate

```
matrix[i][j] = block(<#const int X#>, <#const int Y#>, <#const double size#>, <#const double blockSize#>, <#const double charSize#>, <#const int value#>, <#const int fillColor#>, <#const int textColor#>)
```

The last two arguments of constructor **block** are changed from type **sf::Color** into **int**.

If I create a 4x4 vector of blocks in the **main.cpp** file and call the constructor of **block**, there is no error...

Any help? 
Thanks in advance!

[Update] I attached the scrrenshot of the error message
[image]

Comment: General advice: never put `using namespace std;` in a header.

Comment: or any other `using namespace`

Comment: You should create a copy constructor. `board(const board &)` and even a move constructor because in your case you've got an rvalue assignation.

Comment: not so related maybe, but the `#endif`  should come at the end of file not after the first include... or just use `#pragma once`

Comment: Hi @dkg, why should I have a copy constructor for board? I didn't call any board constructor. Thanks!

Comment: @dkg assuming `sf::RectanlgeShape` and `sf::Test` are copyable, a copy-ctor would solve *nothing* with the offending line. The class `block` members would already be implicitly copy-constructible and there are no RO3 potential isssues/violations. Further no copy-ctor is even being used with the offending line; the constructor and copy-assignment operator are in-play; not the copy-ctor. A *move-assignment* operator may be helpful for performance, but not solve the OP's issue regardless. A `board` constructor has nothing to do with that line whatsoever.

Comment: Post the complete error message.

Comment: And note that "block.h" should include the SFML header that defines `Color`, since it uses it.

Comment: If you select and expand that error in the left-list it should elaborate the expectation vs. provision and where the wheels fall off.

Comment: Hmmm.. What an interesting practice to stop header guard (`#endif /* defined(__Game1024__block__) */`) not at the end of file, but after includes... What is a goal of this ?

Comment: @cgao my mistake, it was about `block` and @WhozCraig is right.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @molbdnilo

I made a stupid mistake that I forgot to include the SFML header in "block.h"

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

Now problem solved! Thanks for all advices. I am new to C++ projects, please feel free to speak out all my bad practices in the code. Very helpful!